# A particle starts its motion from rest and moves with constant acceleration for time $t_1$ and then it retards with constant rate for $t_2$.

Tags: kinematics

And comes to rest. Then the ratio of maximum speed and average speed during the complete motion will be

MY SOLUTION

Let acceleration be a.

Max speed

$$v=at_1$$
Also distance covered will be 
$$s=\frac{(2)(at_1^2)}{2}$$
$$=at_1^2$$
So average speed 
$$=\frac{at_1^2}{t_1+t_2}$$
Taking their ratio gives 
$$\frac{t_1+t_2}{t_1}$$
That’s as far as I got. But the answer is 2:1 and I have no idea on how to get there. Please help me proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Didn’t strike my mind. Thanks

Comment: Except actually the accelerations were not given to have the same magnitude.

Comment: I thought that too, but then we kinda have to assume it, otherwise there is absolutely no way to solve it (there might, I don’t know)

Comment: This can be proved in general

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that the magnitude of the acceleration and deceleration is equal, which is not given.

For the acceleration phase, $v_{max}=a_1t_1$ and distance covered is $\frac12a_1t_1^2$.

For the deceleration phase, $v^2-u^2=-a_1^2t_1^2=-2a_2s$ giving the distance covered as $\frac{a_1^2t_1^2}{2a_2}$. You also have $v=0=a_1t_1-a_2t_2$. Thus the average speed is $$\frac12\frac{a_1t_1^2+\frac{a_1^2t_1^2}{a_2}}{t_1+t_2}=\frac12\frac{a_1t_1^2+a_2t_2^2}{t_1+t_2}$$Taking the ratio$$\frac{v_{avg}}{v_{max}}=\frac12\frac{\frac{a_1t_1^2}{a_1t_1}+\frac{a_2t_2^2}{a_1t_1}}{t_1+t_2}=1/2$$